# Implications between two properties involving the ring $~K[x,y]~$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I tried to solve this problem, but I'm not sure if my solution is correct.
The problem is the following one:
Let $~K~$ be a field, $~f(x)~$ and $~g(x)~$ two irreducible polynomials in $~K[x]~$ with the same grade $~d \geq 2~$. Determine (both for $~d=2~$ and for a general value of $~d~$) the implications between these two proprieties:

$~1.~~$ the ring $~\frac{K[x,y]}{(f(x),g(y)}~$ is a field.

$~2.~~$ the extensions $~\frac{K[x]}{f(x)}~$ and $~\frac{K[x]}{g(x)}~$ of $~K~$ are not isomorphic

I found an example which proves that $~2~$ doesn't imply $~1: ~~~K=Q, ~~~f(x)=x^{2}-2, ~~~g(x)=x^{2}~$

However I wasn't able to find the other implication. Supposing $~1\to 2~$ true I tried to proof this implication using the negation of this sentence, but I wasn't able to get a conclusion. 

Is there a simpler way to prove if the implication $~1\to 2~$ is true or not?

Comment: $x^2$ is not irreducible. So the counterexample doesn't work.

Comment: you are right, I have just tried to do it again. I was able to prove that for all d≥3 the implication 2=>1 is not true, while for =2
 there is an exception: suppose that f and g are two polynomials with grade 2 but the extensions are not isomorphic; that means that f and g have different roots. Let us note k[a] and k[b] these two extensions.: K[x,y]/(f(x),g(y)) will be isomorphic to K[a,b] which is a field. However this is not the same with grade $\geq$3